# Variable in Jupyter Notebook only works within the cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a variable that I use in one cell of the jupyter but when I call it in the next cell it says the variable cannot be found

I've tried creating an instance of the variable before reading the data from the son file. I've tried creating another variable the same as the first and using that one in the next cell.

```
if os.path.isfile("cointegration.json"):
    with open("cointegration.json", "r") as f:
        cointegration_mv = json.load(f)
else:
    cointegration_mv = {}
    for i in range(0, len(usd_pairs)):
        pair_i = usd_pairs[i]
        print(pair_i)
        for j in range(0, i):
            pair_j = usd_pairs[j]
            print("\t+",pair_j)
            if pair_i != pair_j:
                code = pair_i + '_' + pair_j
                print("\t\t=",code)
                cointegration_mv[code] =  get_cointegration(pair_i, pair_j)

    json = json.dumps(cointegration_mv)
    f = open("cointegration.json","w")
    f.write(json)
    f.close()

print(cointegration_mv.keys())

#This does print the keys

#The next cell
print(cointegration_mv.keys())
```

The error is:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7abb854e8cc9> in <module>
----> 1 print(cointegration_mv.keys())

NameError: name 'cointegration_mv' is not defined
```

This happens even when I create an instance of the variable before reading in the data (so I'd expect the keys to just be empty), and when I try duplicating the variable and passing the duplicate.

Comment: Feels like broken installation of `ipython` or `jupyter`. Can you reproduce the error in `ipython`? How about creating a new env (virtualenv or anaconda) and checking there?

Comment: Tried re downloading jupyter notebook, still no luck

Comment: I am not saying to redownload but test ipython and create new env.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is 2 years old but for anyone new to Jupyter notebook having this problem, you most likely have to run the previous cell in order for Jupyter to initialize/declare/store those previous variables. Whenever you run a cell it DOES NOT automatically run the other cells and gets those previous variables. As the guide below explains it best:

> Be aware that it is the order of execution of cells that is important in a Jupyter notebook, not the order in which they appear. Python will remember all the code that was run previously, including any variables you have defined, irrespective of the order in the notebook. Therefore if you define variables lower down the notebook and then (re)run cells further up, those defined further down will still be present

[Jupyter/Python Guide](https://swcarpentry.github.io/python-novice-gapminder/02-variables/index.html)

Comment: Can we set cell dependencies so that when a cell "C" is run, it also runs "A" and "B" before hand if they didn't run already?

Comment: Link seems to be broken :-(

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure you´ve run all the cells.**

For example, if a variable x is defined in the first cell you have to also run this cell. Only then the variable will be defined, ready to be used across all cells. Otherwise, it won´t exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

May be that variable declared in first cell is in local scope.Thats why when calling in second cell giving not defined as error.
try putting your code in function in first cell and then  call that function in second cell